# Form Submit not working in latest chrome build (83)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Chrome : chrome update Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Flow

1. Function `function_name` is called from a page (this page remains the main parent page in the whole scenario) which has a table with multiple records and a record has a hyperlink which fetches more data and displays in an overlay/popup.
2. The code etc. mentioned in the code section in the bottom is on that Popup/Overlay piece where form & iframe exist and facilitate the whole process.
3. On Form submit here another piece of html code is called which is then populated in iframe, please check the target of the iframe.

Issue

The form submit was working earlier for all browsers and post new update it's not 
working on latest chrome build but it is working on other browsers at the moment without any issue.

Explanation of not working

I have added logs, it works as expected till form submit line is called. On Form submit we expect the new html piece to be called and then that to be loaded in the iframe. That page never gets invoked on the latest chrome build (does get invoked in all other browsers), there is no reflection on network tab either which should happen because on form submit another file is called. (happens in all other cases)

Observations

1. The popup flow is initiated from a button click in parent page (as explained in the flow)

   < a href="#" onclick="function(this,val1,val2); return false;">

The code for the same is given above, if the same piece of code is removed from the parent page and then replaced with something else and then again changed back to this same code then it works normally. (I have no clue why!)

2. The behavior is erratic too, once in a blue moon even on latest chrome it works properly, once or twice. But the efficiency of system on all other browsers is 100%.

Code : Minimal (Comments are added for understanding separately)

```
<div id="divid" class="dialog" title="">    
<!-- Iframe -->
    <center>
      <iframe name="frameid" id="frameid" src="/images/somegif.gif" width=820 height=400 frameborder=0 style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0;"></iframe>
    </center>
</div>
    <!-- Form -->
    <form id="formid" name="formid" method="post" action="/somefile.html" target="framename">
       <!-- Some Form Elements -->
    </form>
    <script>
    //Javascript

$(function() {
    $("#divid").dialog({
        width: 860,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        open: function(e, ui) {
            $(this).siblings(".ui-dialog-titlebar").find("button").blur(); 
        },
        close: function() {
            jQuery('#framename').attr('src','/images/somegif.gif')
        }
    });
});

    function function_name(val1,val2) {
      var form_obj;
      form_obj=document.getElementById('formid');
      if (form_obj) {
        //some operation, validation etc.   
        jQuery("#divid").dialog('open');
        somefun(form_obj, "var_name", var_name); //They are working fine 
        somefun2(form_obj, "var_name2", var_name2); //They are working fine
        form_obj.submit();
      }
    }
    </script>
```

> I just noticed that form name and id is same, same goes for the iframe. The developer who wrote this is not with us anymore, in short, not my code.

Comment: Can you fix the script tag at start of JS first so we can test in snippets

Comment: `Code : Minimal` ... too minimal ... Minimal code should demonstrate the issue you have, your code has many issues, with undefined functions and non-existent elements, i.e. what is `somefun` and `somefun2`, what is `#someid`, how is `function_name` called?

Comment: @JaromandaX I agree with you, there are many layers in this flow actually i.e. why I was trying to concentrate on the main flow. I will add more details.

Comment: What does "_it's not working_" mean?

Comment: @Teemu Form submit is not happening, nothing on the network tab. And the control is not passed over to that new page.

Comment: Please put that in the question too ...

Comment: @Teemu It's there, right in the end. I will try to explain it better. I am editing with more codes and better explanation of the whole flow.

Comment: Very similar code on my site seems to work (though the Chrome version is 83.0.4103.101).

Comment: @Teemu I am confused myself, I don't see a reason for it to not work either, there are other observations as well which I would like to add. Please check this after 10 minutes. I am trying to explain things in a better manner, add more details and share my observation. Thanks for your time, please do check this in sometime. It should make more sense.

Comment: @Teemu Please check if now it makes more sense, if more details should be added. Let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Gandalf, found this issue on chromium.
[Issue 1092200: Submitting form whose target is an iframe randomly fail siliently](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1092200)

A bug fix for it was merged into 84, but a bugfix for [Issue 1092313: Form submission takes precedence over window.location navigation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1092313)
 caused a regression, and looks like they are still looking into it..

We are also experiencing the same problem, and watching 1092200

Comment: This helps thanks a lot. Did you guys employ any hacks to fix it? I have and it works